# Check if javascript object/property is defined

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, undefined

So i've read a handful of SO posts and some blogs, but still can't figure out why my code isn't working.

My code:

```
function myFunct(d) {
    if (typeof d.parent.name == "undefined") {
        console.log("undefined") ;} else { console.log("defined") ;}
    }
```

`d` is an object that looks something like:

```
Object { 
children: Object, 
count: 676
}
```

I've tried using `(!d.parent.name)`, `hasOwnProperty`, `===`, and as above using `typeof`. Any suggestions?

The error I recieve is `TypeError: d.parent.name is undefined`

UPDATE:

Ok thanks everyone for the input, and my apologies if the question was confusing. I was actually looking for `d.parent.parent` but tried to simplify the question by using `d.parent`. I think the problem is that `d.parent` is not defined so it doesn't even get to `d.parent.parent`. Sorry for not being more specific!

Comment: @ForceMagic I receive the same error.

Comment: `typeof Object === 'undefined'` is a valid way to use typeof

Comment: @NickSlash sry, my bad :)

Comment: @NickSlash Thanks, unfortunately I still get the same `TypeError`

Comment: can you give this a try? `if (d.parent && typeof d.parent.name === 'undefined')`

Comment: In which line exactly are you getting this error? What does `console.log(d.parent)` give?

Comment: @NickSlash same error :/

Comment: _d is an object that looks something like_ <- this is a little unclear. Why don't you post the d itself?  With all subnodes

Comment: @bergi `console.log(d.parent)` gives `undefined`

Comment: the issue might not b `d`, can you also include the parent object inside it?

Comment: There's no such thing as d.parent, not even in your example :P

Comment: @ForceMagic Ok I updated the original question for `d`

Comment: Oh... well thats odd then

Comment: @ForceMagic Yes sometimes `d.parent` exists and sometimes `d` does not include `parent`. I want to only do something if `d.parnet` exists... am I going about this the wrong way? (also I mistype on my last comment, i meant `d`... sorry about that)

Comment: See answer from @isvforall

Comment: Please put in tested code for a minimal definition of `d` that reproduces the problem (with a `parent` property), At the moment you've used the name of the  global function `Object` in a confusing manner.

Comment: Ok I updated the original question with why I think it wasn't working. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want an undefined-safe check all the way down your object tree, you can use:

```
if( typeof( ((d || {}).parent || {}).name ) === 'undefined') {

}
```

If you have the luxury of having Lodash at your disposal:

```
var d = { 
     parent: {
          name: "Joe"
     }
};

if ( typeof (_.get(d, "parent.name")) === 'undefined' ) {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to check all children with logical `OR`

```
if (typeof d == "undefined" ||
    typeof d.parent == "undefined" ||
    typeof d.parent.name == "undefined") {
// ...
}
```

Comment: Gah I get the same error... I must really be doing something wrong. Thanks though for the suggestions!

Comment: Append `typeof d == "undefined" ||` to the beginning of the if condition

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeof x === 'undefined')
```

Use this, it checks for type as well as value, thats what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the input, however I still receive the same error

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing to an existing value?

Comment: Ya @As3adTintin, if for some reason d.parent itself is undefined, the script will error out before it even gets to checking d.parent.name, be aware of that

Comment: True, why don't you first check if the parent is undefined?

Comment: @jlane09 thanks for the feedback. I receive the same error weather I check for `d.parent` or `d.parent.name`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is the property identifier `parent`. Are you sure your object has the property? The identifier `d` may be invalid because `parent` doesn't exists.